# Finding Maximum Value of Variable Using Only Its Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, computational-mathematics

Assume I have a variable `u`, which is an $m\times n$ array filled with exclusively real values. I want to find the maximum value within this `u` array, given its Fourier Transform `U`, i.e `u = np.fft.ifft2(U)`. Is it possible to obtain this maximum value without doing a full Inverse Fourier Transform?

I'm thinking some type of mathematical trick like [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) might be helpful. I want to avoid the full inverse transform if at all possible due to the computational cost. I would appreciate any help this site's users could provide.